# In R Studio I am getting Java Out of Memory (for RWeka)

Tags: r, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, heap-memory, rweka

Ok, this looks familiar from the Java world, where/how can I allow more memory for RWeka in RStudio.

Error in .jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Not sure how R interfaces to Java and if I can allow more heap space.

Thanks in advance 
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can increase the heap space.
You can do it before loading any rJava dependent package, in this case, RWeka.

To increase the default (512 MB) to 1024MB:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")
```